# How to sum of values from mongo collection using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using java and mongoDB.

In mongo collection that contents 4 documents, I have data like

```
_id, name, key1, key2, status
```

I want to query that collection using java which returns sum of 'key1' of all four documents where status is 1.

How do I write query to get sum of key1???

Here is my workaround:

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
        match.put("status", 1);

    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$match",match));
    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$group",new BasicDBObject("_id", null).append(
                "total", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$totInOutOctets" ))));
    cmdBody.put("pipeline", pipeline);

// Put db command for execution in json array
    networkCapacityTrending.put(db.command(cmdBody));
```

Comment: I fetched all data from collection with status 1 and by iterating cursor I added key1 to a variable to get sum

Comment: @user3322141 You are trying to submit aggregation pipeline documents under a `db.command` method. You want the `.aggregate()` method on the collection. The code given in the answer is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does have a `.group()` method that could be used, but really this is more of a wrapper around the "mapReduce" methods and the better modern approach is to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "status": 1
    }}
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total": { "$sum": "$key1" }
    }}
])
```

Or even without "matching" the documents first:

```
db.collection.agregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total": { 
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ "$status", 1 ] },
                    "$key1"
                    0,
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

For the Java driver, you are essentially just constructing DBObject types. Either by parsing something simple like the JSON shown or programatically:

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject(
    "$match", new BasicDBObject("status", 1)
);

BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject(
    "$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", null).append(
        "total", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$key1" )
    )
);

DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("mycollection");
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(match,group);
```

Take a general look at the [Aggregation to SQL mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation for a basic overview of things you might be familiar with and how to implement them.

Also see [Aggregation Framework and the Java Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)

Comment: Why _id is null in group statement??

Comment: @user3322141 It means group "everything" as opposed to grouping on a particular value of a field. So what you asked for is "all" documents. Other conditions filter the "status". The links are there to help you as well

Comment: but collection method is deprecated and If I used same thing in different way it gives output as 0

Comment: @user3322141 "collection" as used here is an object referring to the collection fetched from the database. `aggregate()` is the method on that. In reality this will return a result DBObject on the left side. Cleared that up in the listing. Again the links are there to guide you with things that are new to you.